# Trouble installing packages from the Debian buster repository

Tags: debian, apt, debian-buster

**Solved! See comments below for the solution.**

I'm trying to install i3 on Debian buster and it can't find the package. I'm not sure what I'm missing so I can install this package.

These are the errors that I'm getting:

```
> apt install i3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package i3
```

```
> apt install i3-wm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package i3-wm
```

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

I've tried running `apt update` and `apt-get update`, before trying to install the package but got the same error.

Here's the Debian repo: https://packages.debian.org/sid/i3

And the tracker: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/i3-wm

In case it helps, I tried installing [Zeal](https://packages.debian.org/buster/zeal) but am getting the same error.

Am I missing a setting or something to be able to install these packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is missing these lines:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

Then `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt install i3`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks Esa!

Answer (score 2):

You currently only have the LTS and updates repositories. These have only updates, not all packages. You're missing the base Debian repositories, i.e.:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks Michael!